# Как обновить данный из одной таблицы БД и удалить из другой?

Tags: python, база-данных, обновление

Как обновить и удалить значения опр. ячейки в таблице бд?

Есть команда о переводе баллов. Нужно обновить значение баланс из иной таблицы user_vk_base (у Отправителя уменьшить, а у получателя увеличить). А из таблицы user_act_trade удалить запись с опр. кодом (code_trade), что указал пользователь в команде по окончанию изменений в балансе (завершение переводов баллов)

Можете подсказать? А то в интернете не нашёл ответа, а те, что имеются не смогли помочь с моей проблемой.

```
    if len(match)==4 and match[0] =='мой' and match[1] =='код' and match[2] =='перевода':
    
    code_trade = match[3]
    cursor.execute("UPDATE user_vk_base SET Баланс = 10 WHERE Баланс = 100")
    cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM user_act_trade WHERE Кодсделки = '{code_trade}' ")
```

[image: Таблица с трейд. заявками]

Comment: вот вы пишете "у Отправителя уменьшить, а у получателя увеличить", а что вы делаете в коде: "UPDATE user_vk_base SET Баланс = 10 WHERE Баланс = 100"?

Comment: Это образно. Там должно быть вычисление, где БалансОтправителя =БалансОтправителя-СуммаОбмена
БалансПолучателя=БалансПолучателя+СуммаОбмена

Comment: так в чем дело? ))

Comment: Не могу заменить значение (содержание) в опр. ячейке. И не могу удалить опр. запись таблицы из бд)

Comment: А можно увидеть, как вы это делаете, и узнать, как же компьютер сопротивляется вашим попыткам это сделать?

Comment: В том то и дело, что никак. Код выполняется, но ничего в таблицах не изменяется вовсе. Это ладно если ошибку выдвинуло, а так вообще ничего говорящего.

Comment: Ну я добавил в вопрос таблицу. Не знаю поможет ли это решению моей проблемы, но думаю это что-то с моим ПК, а не кодом

Comment: Может вы не в ту базу пишете, которую проверяете )

Comment: Я тупой. Тут он не воспринимал столбцы на русском